# Selecting best Sentence among N- best sentences in C#

Tags: c#, regex, streamreader

I have text file in which text is arranged sentences wise.
Each sentence is repeated 3 times consecutively.The only difference among sentence in each  group is the tag occurrence number.The tags are [loc] , [Time] and [PER]. consider the below example.

```
Match between [Loc]India[/Loc] and [Loc]Seri Lanka[/Loc] will start at [Time]12 o'clock[/TIME]  
Match between [Loc]India[/Loc] and [Loc]Seri Lanka[/Loc] will start at 12 o'clock   
Match between [Loc]India[/Loc] and Seri Lanka will start at [Time]12 o'clock[/TIME]  
[PER]Dhoni[/PER] will lead Indian Team  
[PER]Dhoni[/PER] will lead [PER]Indian Team[/PER]  
Dhoni  will lead Indian Team
```

My objective is to select those sentence in each group of sentences which have maximum number of tags. e.g in 1st group sentence no.1 which have total 
three tags [Loc],[loc] and [Time] similarly sentence 2 in the 2nd group.
I tried with StreamReader, but I was unable to skip sentences.

Comment: Please edit your question using code formatting. It's unreadable as it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting best sentence among N-best sentence in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860559/selecting-best-sentence-among-n-best-sentence-in-c-sharp)

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

If the tags actually appear in the sentences then just do a count.

(Im writing this in VB.net but the syntax is essentially the same)

```
Dim sen1 as String = between [Loc]India[/Loc] and [Loc]Seri Lanka[/Loc] will start at [Time]12 o'clock[/TIME] 
Dim split as String() = sen1.split("/"c)
Dim senCount as Integer = split.count
```

There, now you know that sentence 1 has 3 tags.

You could even turn it into a function like this -

```
Private function tagCount(byval thisSentence As String)
     Dim split as String() = thisSentence.split("/"c)
     Dim senCount as Integer = split.count
     Return senCount
End Function
```

then loop through your sentences to determine which one has the most tags.